# Проблема с обновлениями Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

Прописываю команду  - sudo apt update, получаю в ответ:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, мои дальнейшие действия по исправлению данной ситуации.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Духсообщества, тебе надо в банк уже идти работать

Comment: Отключи репу `ppa beinerl` и сделай `apt update` ещё раз.

Comment: @donRumata, ситуацию не поменяло, лишь убрались строчки про beinerl, с micahflee все в силе: "Репозиторий «https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release» не содержит файла Release"

Comment: `Sorry, there's no software in this PPA at the moment.` а зачем тебе репа, в которой нет софта? https://launchpad.net/~micahflee/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: @donRumata, ничего не менял, все стоит как и стояло изначально, ну можно, конечно, удалить все репы, но с каких получать обновы? Или данное поведение считается адекватным и не стоит ничего предпринимать?

Comment: `с каких получать обновы` - эммм... с тех, которые тебе нужны?

Comment: @donRumata, я это к тому, что отключение не решит эту проблему, и, возможно, проблема только с данными репами. Откуда именно получать обновления - для меня не имеет большого значения, главное, чтобы не было конфликтов и таких ошибок

Comment: `отключение не решит эту проблему` в смысле не решит? У тебя на скрине ошибка, которая говорит, что та репа, которую ты добавил - бесполезна в том дистре, который используешь.

Comment: @donRumata, так у меня ошибки на все добавленные репы (на 2)

Comment: На скрине - только 2 репы. Значит ты кинул плохой скрин, но хочешь, чтобы тебе дали правильное решение. Супер!

Comment: @donRumata, ну да, на скрине 2 репы, на которые ошибки, я и подписан только на эти 2 репы...

Comment: Т.е. на вивальди.ком, на убунту.ком, на докер.ком ты не подписан?

Comment: @donRumata, на вивальди был подписан, но уж удалил, на все другое - нет, даже не был

Comment: `но уж удалил` - твой скриншот считает иначе. `даже не был` - мы точно говорим про один и тот же скрин? Ты сам-то его смотрел?

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)